# Querying attachment info from ArcGIS map service?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, map-service, feature-service

Like feature layers have the `queryAttachmentInfos()` method to fetch attachment info, is there something like this to fetch attachment info from a map service (ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer)?

My app flow is as follows

1. query the map service based on some user defined criteria
2. set info templates for the returned features (attributes + geometry) (this is also where i specify `showAttachments: true` but again no luck)
3. add features to `map.graphics` and show the info window (custom popup in my case)

I have also tried using the attachment editor and the attribute inspector but with no luck.

Should i use the relationship query task? The problem with using the relationship query, i assume, would be that it would be impossible to know if the related record is an attachment or some other related record.